# NSData returning 0 bytes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am trying to load the image in the following way. But when I call my `loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)inURL` function as `[self loadImagesFromURL:url]` in my `tableView` its showing 0 bytes.
How to get the value of `(delta)NSData` in my `tableview`?, which is declared as global...

```
NSURLConnection* connection;
NSMutableData* delta;

- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)inURL {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (conn) {
        delta = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }    
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [delta appendData:data];

    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     
    NSURL *urlink=[NSURL URLWithString:[[objectsForImages objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self loadImageFromURL:urlink];
    UIImage *imageForAz=[UIImage imageWithData:delta];
    cell.imageView.image=imageForAz; 

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you do receive data from the url ?

Comment: yeah,the data is getting received...but cannot access the data in my tableview function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting confused by the asynchronicity. If `loadImageFromURL:` were synchronous, e.g. wrapping `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, your code would work as you would expect; `loadImageFromURL:` would block while fetching, and return when `delta` was populated.

However, this is all asynchronous, so what you actually need to do is implement `connectionDidFinishLoading:` in your delegate (which in this case is `self`) and have it set `cell.imageView.image` there.

Rewriting some of your code accordingly (I assume that you removed extraneous code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for the purpose of this example):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {     
    NSURL *urlink=[NSURL URLWithString:[[objectsForImages objectForKey:[arrayOfCharacters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self loadImageFromURL:urlink];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *imageForAz=[UIImage imageWithData:delta];
    cell.imageView.image=imageForAz;
}
```

Check out the [URL Loading System Programming Guide on NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) for more details / examples.

Comment: thanks alot Kristian for your kind reply,but how come i access my tableview cell in my connectionDidFinishLoading funtion?...have declared cell as global,but its of no use..:(

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if you'd ask that. You'll want a `delta` per `cell`, and a mapping from each connection started to those two. I'll try to dig out an example for you.

Comment: Christian thanks alot for the favour...i have resolved it with the help of....http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Comment: ...that code has been written with some quite basic misunderstandings, I'm somewhat unconvinced by it...